# Get Azure Queue name from an instance of IAsyncCollector<T>

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Can I get the queue name from an instance of `IAsyncCollector<T>`?

I have a method which adds messages to a queue, where the queue is a parameter.
It is called by many functions and each of them injects a different queue.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddToQueue(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, IAsyncCollector<string> webhooksQueue)
```

Within the body of the method I would like to log an information to which queue did I add a message.
I can see that there is a private field on the instance of the queue, but I don't want to get its value with reflection.

[image]

Comment: Where do you configure the name of the queue and connection string? Isn't the signature usually something like: `[Queue("QueueName", Connection = "QueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> webhooksQueue`?

Comment: @ChrisB Yes it is. And that's where I configure it. But imagine having 23 functions which all have their own queue - they pass the IAsyncCollector to the common class to handle the shared logic.

Comment: Also, I don't want to pass the queue name as string parameter to that method, because that would be error prone - I, and everybody else who uses this code in my team, would have to remember to pass proper string.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you pass the queue name to the common class? Not the most elegant solution

Comment: @ChrisB - yeah, I want to avoid that as risky and error prone.

Comment: Haha - I posted the comment above just after you wrote you don't want to pass it in, sorry!